# I want to prove that $ \int_{-1}^{+1}xp_{s}(x)p_{r}(x)dx=\delta_{r,s+1}\frac{2r}{(2r+1)(2r-1)}+\delta_{s,r+1}\frac{2s}{(2s+1)(2s-1)}. $

Tags: integration, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Please make an illustration to me in proving of the following.

> **Problem:** Assume that 
>   $ p_{n}(x)$ is a Legendre polynomials.
>   I want to prove that
>   $$ \int_{-1}^{+1}xp_{s}(x)p_{r}(x)dx=\delta_{r,s+1}\frac{2r}{(2r+1)(2r-1)}+\delta_{s,r+1}\frac{2s}{(2s+1)(2s-1)}.  $$
>   For proof of this, I don't want to use the following recurrence formula 
>   $$ (n+1)p_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1)xp_{n}(x)-np_{n-1}(x). $$

**What I have done:**

> First of all, I used Rodrigues' formula:
>   $$ p_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n}n!}D^{n}((x^{2}-1)^{n}) $$
>   so 
>   $$ \int_{-1}^{+1}xp_{s}(x)p_{r}(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{+1}x(\frac{1}{2^{r}r!}D^{r}((x^{2}-1)^{r}))(\frac{1}{2^{s}s!}D^{s}((x^{2}-1)^{s}))dx$$
>   After this step, it seems that I have to use *repeated integration by parts* (because the proof of Rodrigues' formula is like that), but I can't use it.

Comment: Is there a reason why the recurrence relation can't be used.  The easiest proof is to isolate $x\p(x)$ from the recursion, then use orthogonality.

Comment: Because I wanna use this and prove that recurrence formula.

Comment: If I remember, the recurrence relation follows easily from the differential equation.  Can you use that?

Comment: @skbmoore 
Yes, it can be obtainable from generating functions.
But, I want to do that in this way.